# Extract to %appdata%\folder1

Tags: c#, subdirectory, sharpziplib

I want to extract with SharpZipLib to extract.

I use this for extract on `%appdata`% but i want to extract in a subfolder of Roaming

```
string appdata = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

My question is how I extract to `%appdata%\subfolder`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Path.Combine` to generate absolute path for your subfolder -

```
string subFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdata,"subfolder");
```

Comment: Thanks again it works perfectly, sorry for my bad English because I´m Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's two ways of doing this really, one using string concatenation and the other using using Path.Combine

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\subfolder";
```

Or

```
string folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "subfolder");
```

Personally I am not sure which is the "better" option, I guess when it comes down to it they do the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried it? This won't even compile since `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is not string and `Path.Combine` expects string parameter.

Comment: Now I feel silly, I copy / pasted it from something I had open but in the process of removing certain things from it I broke it entirely. Thanks for pointing out.